# Abbreviating number ranges in BibLaTeX

Tags: biblatex

I'm using [`biblatex`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) for bibliography management, and I'm required to use numbered citation style where references are sorted after citation order. Thus, I've loaded the package like this:

```
\usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex}
```

Now when I cite multiple sources in the same citation

```
Some statement \cite{source1,source2,source3,source4}.
```

I get the following result:

> Some statement [1, 2, 3, 4].

but I'd rather have the following:

> Some statement [1-4].

Ideally, it should let two citations remain as [1, 2], while three or more should become [1-3] etc. I've looked in [the documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) for options that define this behavior, but apparently I don't know what I'm looking for. (Most of my internet searches drown in results on how to abbreviate page ranges...)

Comment: you should check the `sortcites=true` option or the `numeric-comp` citation style (see section 3.3.1 of the manual)

Comment: @Guido: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! Eventually, `style=numeric-comp,sorting=none` gave me what I wanted. If you put it in an answer, I can give you rep for it - otherwise I'll probably put the answer up here myself for completeness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the `biblatex` manual (section 3.3.1) the `numeric-comp` citation style

> is similar to the `cite` package and the `sort&compress` option of the `natbib` package in numerical mode. For example, instead of “[8, 3, 1, 7, 2]” this style would print “[1–3, 7, 8]”.