# Abbreviating number ranges in BibTeX

Tags: bibtex

I am trying to do the same thing as this poster, but in BibTeX:
[Abbreviating number ranges in BibLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159792/abbreviating-number-ranges-in-biblatex)

I cannot get BibLaTeX to work for me (see [Loading .bib files with BibLaTeX on Overleaf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/598570/loading-bib-files-with-biblatex-on-overleaf)), and it compiles very slowly anyway.  Does anyone know if it is possible to achieve this result in BibTeX?

Comment: The answer to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3871/35864 has an extensive survey of different methods to achieve compressed citations (two of which work for BibTeX, one for `biblatex`).

Comment: Thank you!!  Adding \usepackage{cite} did the trick.  I also added [nosort] to get exactly what I was going for.